# How do I convert if to a math equation

Tags: math

I know how to convert other logic gates
ceiling(a/2+b/2)OR
round(a/4+b/4)AND
abs(ceiling(a/2+b/2)-1)NOR
abs(round(a/4+b/4)-1)NAND
abs(abs(a+b-1)-1)XOR
abs(a+b-1)XNOR
I am using a graph to at least view the collatz conjecture but I need a if gate for it to work and that is not allowed in math unless your putting it in a piece of code.
But it is complicated and I don't know how to make it.

```
if(Number.isInteger(x)==true) {
  x=x*3+1
} else {
  x=x/2
}
```

Since July this has been a concerning thought in my head.
Does anyone have the answer to this?

Comment: If 0 is false and 1 is true, then "if A then B else C" is AB + (1-A)C

Comment: what exactly is `A,B` ? Is it bool,int (signed/unsigned),float, fixed? those `AND,OR,XOR` are boolean,bitwise or fuzzy ? What exactly you want to compute brunchlesly? is it (C++ syntax)  `(x%2) ? x/2 : 3*x+1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I would approach it this way:

ODD: ceiling(x/2) - floor(x/2)

F: x/2 + ODD(x)(5x/2 + 1)